# Refreshing tokens with GIDSignIn iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, google-signin, gidsignin

I am currently using google sign to authenticate users to my app, but am having problems with the id_token after it's been refreshed. I have the following variables set up. One is for the iOS client and one is for the server. This is following AWS examples. I am using AWS to access the server and therefore need to have a client id and web application id.

```
static let GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7dde.apps.googleusercontent.com"

// Backend web application client ID
static let GOOGLE_WEB_APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx65ap.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

When I first log in the application it works as expected. I get an id token back that has the following:

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "at_h ash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx65ap.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "email_verified": true,
  "azp": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7dde.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "email": "2222MyNewEmailIsHere@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1475747692,
  "exp": 1475751292
}
```

You can see that the "aud" matches the GOOGLE_WEB_APPLICATION_ID and the "azp" matches GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.

However if I do a refreshTokensWithHandler like so:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.refreshTokensWithHandler { (GIDAuthentication, error) in

                self.googleAuth = GIDAuthentication;
                self.completeGoogleLogin()
}
```

I get a problem with the response. The id token is being refreshed correctly and thus have a new id token. However the "aud" seems to be overwritten with the client id. This happens whether the token has expired or not.

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "at_h ash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7dde.apps.googleusercontent.com"",
  "sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "email_verified": true,
  "azp": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7dde.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "email": "2222MyNewEmailIsHere@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1475747692,
  "exp": 1475751292
}
```

As you can see, the "aud" and the "azp" is the same in the second response. When I then go to make a request to the server it's complaining that the token can't be verified.

I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this? It seems like an issue with GIDSignIn maybe.

Comment: Hi. Banging my head around this exact issue almost a year later. Did you find an explanation of why this happens or how to fix?